# Is High Friction Aggregate a type of stone or treatment applied to a stone?

Tags: construction, stone, rock

I am doing some research about decorative stones and came across high friction aggregate.  I am a bit confused and here are my two questions:

1. Is High Friction Aggregate a separate type of stone OR is it a treatment applied to stones?
2. If it is a type of treatment, why would someone want to use it on granite/veneer/quartzite stones? I ask because the treatment is used to make skid resistant surfaces.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a residential use.

It is more a class of stone than a type.

For roadways, high friction aggregates (calcined bauxite is the most common component) is applied (bonded would be a better description) in areas where skids frequently occur, to improve traction.